# Why are Outlook REST API requests returning 404?

Tags: outlook-restapi

My app has been making API calls to the Outlook REST APIs ([Mail](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations), [Calendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/calendar-rest-operations), [Contacts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/contacts-rest-operations)) for a while now with no problem. The app makes calls like:

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Messages
```

Lately, all requests have started returning a 404 HTTP error. What has changed?

Answer (score 0):

The `/ews/odata` endpoint was the original URL form used when the Outlook REST APIs were released in preview. When the APIs moved out of preview, a new URL form was introduced that will allow for a better versioning scheme. The released URL form is `/api/{version}`, where `{version}` can currently be `1.0` or `beta`.

The preview endpoint is being deprecated. That means you'll need to update your app to use the production endpoint. See this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/09/02/deprecating-the-rest-api-preview-endpoint.aspx) for the full announcement.